# EOF in reading pickle in Jupyter notebook, but not in python interpreter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem in opening a pickle in a Jupyter notebook. Unfortunately, I cannot share the data file, so I cannot provide a working example.

For my data analysis I use a single conda environment `ai`. The same environment is used in a Jupyter notebook.

I have a pickle that is 67M in size.

1. If I launch `python` in a shell after activating the conda environment `ai`, I am able to load the pickle file with `df = pd.read_pickle("file.pickle")`. No problems at all.
2. If I read the same file in a Jupyter notebook using the same environment `ai`, I get an `EOF` error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8405/3858244629.py in 
----> 1 df = pd.read_pickle("file.pickle")

~/miniconda3/envs/ai/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression, storage_options)
    215                     # RawIOBase, BufferedIOBase, TextIOBase, TextIOWrapper, mmap]";
    216                     # expected "IO[bytes]"
--> 217                     return pickle.load(handles.handle)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    218             except excs_to_catch:
    219                 # e.g.

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Why? Do I need to change some RAM usate limits in the notebook? I know my description is a little generic, but I cannot provide the data file.

Comment: Which Python versions do you have within and outside of Jupyter?

Comment: Maybe I have not understood your question, sorry. I use the same conda envionment inside and outside of VSC, that uses python 3.8.12 (that is the same version that produced the pickle files).